# код для точки в треугольнике C++

Tags: алгоритм, вычислительная-геометрия

Даны три вершины треугольника с координатами (координаты вводятся с клавиатуры) А(х<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>) B(х<sub>2</sub>,y<sub>2</sub>) и С(х<sub>3</sub>,y<sub>3</sub>).

Имеются координаты еще одной точки D(х<sub>4</sub>,yх<sub>4</sub>).

Нужно определить, принадлежит эта точка треугольнику или нет, а также проверить, возможен ли треугольник с такими точками.

Comment: http://cpp.mazurok.com/triangle/

Comment: Треугольник возможен с любыми 3 точками)

Comment: Ну и что? Неравенство треугольника тоже не можете проверить?

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka мне лично идея не нравится. Тут можно работать а целях числах и без уравнений прямой. А за get с копированием переменной - как-то не очень.

Comment: Треугольник с данными точками возможен всегда. ПРограмма по ссылке очень хорошая.

Comment: @pavel Формально, если 3 точки на одной прямой, то это не треугольник

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем с проверки существования. Если все точки попарно различны (не совпадают никакие две) - треугольник, естественно, возможен. При проверке не забывайте, что точное сравнение `==` для чисел с плавающей точкой может давать сюрпризы :)

Что до нахождения точки внутри - то на ваш выбор два самых распространенных метода (есть и другие).

1. Посчитать площади треугольников ABD, BCD, CAD и сравнить их сумму с площадью треугольника ABC.
2. Посмотреть для каждой пары вершин, лежат ли третья вершина и проверяемая точка с одной стороны от прямой, проходящей через эту пару вершин. Вычисления еще проще.

Вот немного математики:

Считаются произведения (1,2,3 - вершины треугольника, 0 - точка):

```
(x1-x0)*(y2-y1)-(x2-x1)*(y1-y0)
(x2-x0)*(y3-y2)-(x3-x2)*(y2-y0)
(x3-x0)*(y1-y3)-(x1-x3)*(y3-y0)
```

Если они одинакового знака, то точка внутри треугольника, если что-то из этого - ноль, то точка лежит на стороне, иначе точка вне треугольника.

См. [здесь](http://www.cyberforum.ru/mathematics/thread8234.html).

P.S. Ваш вопрос с тегом C++ явно подпадает под закрытие как *"Сообщение содержит лишь текст задачи, в котором нет описания проблемы, либо вопрос чисто формален («как мне выполнить это задание»)."* С тэгом "Алгоритмы", на мой взгляд, имеет право на существование.